# how to create react native link like WhatsApp group chat link

Tags: react-native, hyperlink, whatsapp

I want the link to navigate to a certain page and execute a function using the data in the link.

Answer (score 0):

There's platform called [branch](https://branch.io/en) that's makes the process of creating a link to a certain page very easy, for react-native, you can use its lib [react-native-branch](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking-attribution).
I've used it already and it's very good.The branch.io provides some analytics metadata about how many times a user clicked on the link you've created for example.